# Water mages in moder war

Tags: internal-consistency, magic, warfare

Could water mages be useful in a modern war?

**Range**:50 meters

**Cost**: physical energy similar to mild to heavy exercise.

**Basic level**

Ice manipulation: can turn water to ice and ice to water.

Wave calling: can summon waves from a hereby water source.

Super pressure stream: can create streams of super pressurized water strong enough to cut metal.

**Intermediate level**.

Control plants

Extract water from the air

Healing by repairing organic tissue and stopping blood flow.

**Master level**

Hold person: hold a person in place by taking control of the water in their body.

Organic water extraction:  ability to extract water from organic creatures

Would these abilities be of any use on a modern battlefield? If so, would it only apply to the master level or could the lower levels still be of use?

Comment: Nicklodeon called, they want Katara back. Also I think you meant control plants?

Comment: Why was this closed as a duplicate? These 2 questions are similar but they are obviously very different at the same time.

Comment: @TheSquare-CubeLaw Are you sure that water magic and earth magic are the same? What are your criteria for duplicates?

Comment: @Otkin the water one was closed as opinion based. I believe earth, fire, air and heart would also be, on the same basis.

Comment: @TheSquare-CubeLaw Then why are you closing this one as a duplicate? Why are you not voting to close this one as opinion-based? Is duplicate in this case just an attempt to expedite closure?

Comment: @otkin no, I had even forgotten I had this hammer. I think both of these questions boil down to "elemental mages in modern war". You could use the darkspore elements instead (death, plant, robot, quantum and lava) and it'd still be the same question.

Comment: @TheSquare-CubeLaw I can agree that this question needs additional details and clarifications. However, I disagree with your evaluation of this question as a duplicate. Yes, all questions in this series can be seen as 'utility of elemental mages in modern war'. But this does not take into consideration that each query contains a unique set of spells. It is not given that if water mages are useful earth mages are also useful. I am also not sure that duplicate is the same as a suggestion to merge all questions into one. Moreover, I think that merge would make the question too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely.

Being able to cut through metal means you can cut through people.

Healing is healing - and not having to carry around medical supplies for it seriously reduces what medics need to carry.

Not having to carry water everywhere is also a massive weight reduction.